# snakemake + singularity, getting rid of python dependency

Tags: snakemake, singularity-container

I have a slightly weird question: consider the case of a containerized workflow where the entire workflow is executed using a single singularity container.
This still requires python to be available on the system to invoke snakemake --use-singularity, right? 
How can I get rid of this dependency as well? Can I just install python, snakemake, and singularity in my container and execute

```
singularity exec my-container snakemake --use-singularity
```

Is this safe to use with cluster configurations?

Edit: does not seem to work at all - I could not get snakemake with singularity to work from within another container...

Comment: *bump*. obviously, this only makes sense in a cluster environment since I could otherwise just call snakemake without --singularity in its own container...

Answer (score 0):

To the best of my knowledge, you can't launch a singularity container from within another singularity container. So containerizing snakemake itself in a HPC environment without root privileges is a non-starter. (Although I would be delighted to be corrected on this.)
You can, however, [containerize the environments](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/deployment.html#containerization-of-conda-based-workflows) used by each rule, either individually or jointly. The `--containerize` option will generate a Dockerfile that can be used used to build a Docker image (`docker build -t repo/name:tag .`) on a host with root privileges. Push this to Docker Hub or similar and then specify the repo/name:tag in the [container item](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/deployment.html#running-jobs-in-containers) of the snakemake rule.

If you want to containerize snakemake itself, try [cloud execution](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/executing/cloud.html#cloud-execution) with `--use-kubernetes`. This uses the [latest official snakemake imag](https://hub.docker.com/r/snakemake/snakemake/tags)e as the base container by default. It is still up to you to containerize the remaining environments but with Kubernetes *all* environments will need containers.